How to click pseudo element using Playwright?
I have a <input type="search"> element,
and I'm trying to click the clear pseudo element using Playwright-typescript.

I've managed to make it visible manually using these instructions, but not via Playwright.
Is there any way to accomplish that?

input can't have pseudo elements and they are not clickable.

It's a User-Agent pseudo element, I've added a screenshot

This element is browser element and can not be targeted with any selector. Also don't rely on this behaviour as not all browsers will have this clear button

There's no point in testing browser-specific features like this. You can already assume clicking the X works. If it doesn't, it's a bug in the browser, not your application. You have no control over this from JS, just like you have no programmatic control over the browser toolbar appearance. Think of it as part of the "skin", not the DOM. Is there something you're really trying to test?

Yes I agree with @ggorlen on this , we are testing the application not the browser.

In general, consider to use “Playwright Test Generator and Test Inspector” - see https://www.lambdatest.com/learning-hub/playwright-futuristic-features
